# Master View implementation using MVVM in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a silverlight datagrid to which I am binding an observable collection from the viewmodel. There is a detail view page which will display different properties of the object in the collection when user selects a row of the datagrid. My requirement is when user updates any properties in the detail view; the data should be updated in the data grid also. How to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is simply to bind both the datagrid row and the control displaying the selected object. The simplest way is to use a ICollectionView (returned by a CollectionViewSource from the original ObservableCollection), bind the grid's ItemsSource to that, and then bind the control's DataContext to the ICollectionView's CurrentItem. That way, when the grid's selected item changes, the CurrentItem of the ICollectionView is updated, and that item is displayed in the detail view.

I think it's quite easy but if you need additional details or sample source code I'll elaborate.